# OpenERP 6.1 datetime formatting

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-6

Why does

```
o.create_order.strftime("%d %B %Y")
```

returns nothing when

```
time.strftime("%d %B %Y")
```

returns the date "10 february 2013"???

o.create_order is a timestamp according to postgresql. 
It contains "30/11/2012 09:38:34" as seen on the openErp sale order - Other information tab.
It is stored as "2012-11-30 08:38:34.272" when querying the database.
So I would expect to see "30 November 2012" but get nothing instead.
Am I misinterpreting the syntax?

I tested this from python 3.3:

```
>>> d1=datetime.datetime.today()
>>> print(d1.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
10 february 2013
```

How do I get it to work in OpenOffice Writer?

And by the way how do I get "February" instead of "february"?

Comment: Why does the ORM return a string like this for date/datetime fields? Seems a bit undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

Because `o.create_order` returns a string and not a datetime object, even if, internally, the database column is a timestamp. The OpenERP ORM returns a string in ISO 8601 format.

You need to use the `formatLang` method which is available in RML reports or create a `datetime` object using the `datetime` python module.

Try this:

```
datetime.strftime('%d %B %Y', o.create_order')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `o.create_order` returns a string. So first you have to convert your string date into **datetime** format and then again you can convert it into any format you want as a string.

Try this:

#Converts string into datetime format.
`dt1 = datetime.strptime(o.create_order,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

#Converts datetime into your given formate and returns string.
`dt2 = datetime.strftime(dt,"%d %B %Y")`

Hope this will solve your problem.